# How to run child process in CasperJS with SlimerJS as engine

Tags: casperjs, child-process, slimerjs

Is it possible?

Like we can do with Phantom engine by

```
var cp = require('child_process');
```

But it doesn't work when I use Slimer as engine.

I looked into the doc of slimer and it seems that Slimer doesn't have the child_process module. Is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no SlimerJS support for this currently. However, judging by [this feature request](https://github.com/laurentj/slimerjs/issues/215) it is both possible and likely to happen soon. (I say that as the activity, and offer of a patch, is only a month old.)

SlimerJS is pure JavaScript, so quite easy to hack on (compared to PhantomJS, which also requires knowledge of C++ and Qt). Especially if you only needed one of Windows or Linux support, and only need to target one Gecko version, I'm betting you could do a custom patch to get it working in a couple of hours?